# How can I get 2 divs with same class to fadeIn their child element simultaneously when clicked?

Tags: jquery, class, click, fadein

I am scratching my head at the moment.

I have an image with 2 buttons which could possibly turn to 3,4,5 and so on. Each button has a click function that will fade in an information box next to the image. The information box will differ depending on each button, so for instance button 1 could be about sheep and button 2 could be about dogs. I would then have the function of clicking each button to reveal the info boxes one by one on a fadeToggle.

The problem I am having is that the container which each of there are in have the same class so i am getting the second child element of that container and fading it in but it only fades in the first one clicked etc etc.

Please see the markup below and explained.

**Jquery**

```
    var children = $(".anatomy").children().eq(1);

$(document).ready(function(){     
    fadeDetail();
});

function fadeDetail() {

    $(".anatomy div.control").click(function() {
        children.each(function(){
        $(this).fadeToggle('slow');
        })
    });

}
```

Html - Here the .control button opens up the .detail box which is set to display: none; There could be several of these boxes on one page each with different content in the .detail div.

```
<article class="anatomy">
    <!-- custom field data will allow these to be positioned via cms-->
       <div class="control" style="left:; right:; top:300px; bottom:;">
            <img src="img/more-button.png" alt="more-button" width="37" height="36" />
        </div>
        <!-- hide this div as it will not be needed. Only needed when asked to open-->
        <div class="detail">
        <img src="img/articles/detail-image.png" alt="detail-image" width="340" height="217" />
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>Hello</p>
        </div>
</article>
```

I think I am almost nearly there but my knowledge is not going as far as this I am afraid.

Any tips would be great,

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you just need to toggle `div.detail` on click of `div.control`. Can you try rewriting your function like below,

```
$(".anatomy div.control").click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle('slow');        
});
```

Comment: Hey Vega, sometimes the most simp,e fo things can work most of the time. Thanks of the feedback

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.control').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});
```

Comment: Using `.control` is faster in modern browsers but this will end up binding all elements with class `control` in the whole page instead of those inside `.anatomy`

Comment: Sure, there could also be other sections with class `anatomy` that he doesn't want binded.

Comment: I don't know.. I am just speculating.. It may or may not be the case.. however your selector is broad and may not just select the intended elements.

Comment: I don't disagree with you although I don't find it all that necessary to speculate.  My example solves his posted question just as yours does and we both are making speculations either way.  I do appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just add a class to each of the elements you wish to hide when an item gets clicked and then call

```
  $('.classToFade').fadeToggle('slow')
```